# Media Queries, Mobile Img rendering & Android CSS Gradient Issue

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have been building a webpage for sometime now with the aid of others here and there, and I'm only just starting to use Media Queries.

The issue that I have been experienceing, is that one of my images specifically the backgorund image on my site, will not load on mobile. However on a browser the image loads perfectly fine. I have looked to see if it is an address issue, but all is fine there. I have attempted to use percentages, but again still no luck.

I do get the alt message of the text, followed by a tiny question mark in the middle of the missing image.

on another note, **CSS3** graidients are failing to load on android when browsing my page again I have no idea what the issue could be they work fine on a desktop.

Any help on these topics would be greatly appreciated and would aleiviate my headache.

**[My webpage](http://www.scandalband.co.uk)**

** SOLUTION **

iOS cannot load images above a core size of 1500px give or take.
also added

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your console it says:

`The value "device-width;" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.`

After having a look at the relevant html meta tag I see that you're using `;` to separate. That's wrong, use `,` instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

**Edit**

As you're using xHtml make sure to avoid common CSS errors.

[CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.scandalband.co.uk/&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Corrigate the following:

Line 60: `font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Line 94: Remove the `,`

Line 179/180: Use `:` instead of `=`

Line 338: `font-size: 16px;` you need the `-` and specifiy a unit

Line 430: `position: relative;` instead of `postion: relative;`

Comment: I have made the changes, still no luck... Do you think it could be the file type?

Comment: You now have two viewport meta tags. Remove the first one an try again. If it still fails try to remove the media-queries completly from your css file. If it still doesn't work something else must be the problem. Are you using javascript to manipulate the element? Also use `/` to close your meta tags as you're using xhtml.

Comment: I made the changes, removed the extra veiwport, added the /, and removed the MQ's still no luck. However the backgound image now works on andriod just not IOS, no idea why.

Comment: @Beaniie can you upload the updated version? So I can test... Also I can see that you've several errors in your `style.css`. Line 179/180, use `:` instead of `=`. On line 338 it has to be `font-size: 16;` not `font size: 16;`. xHtml doesn't forgive you much that's why you should avoid errors like that. Please also consider using HTML5 instead..

Comment: Im not to good a debugging, as you can see. xD I have uploaded a new version and will continue to do so, ive rebuilt the site 3 times over working out errors and kinks in the code at late. this is the cleanest I've gotton it.

Comment: @Beaniie I can't see the updated version. There are still two viewport tags and the closing `/` are still missing. Please provide the updated version. I added some errors in your CSS to my answer. Please make sure to remove them.

Comment: I have updated the version on the server. www.scandalband.co.uk is the link. it should show the updated version. and thank you I will.

Comment: if you can see the updated page try clearing your cookies. other than that i cant see why the old verssion is still showing. the server is delivering the updated version to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46153/discussion-between-enyce12-and-beaniie)